# Must successive terms in Taylor series expansion become smaller?

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion

We use the second derivative test to determine whether a stationary point is max or min. However that is only valid if further expansion of the series does not lead to a reversal in the sign of the expression. Is there any result which guarantees that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The second derivative test definitively states that the stationary point is a min/max when the second derivative at the point is positive/negative respectively. It fails when the second derivative is $0$ (or doesn't exist). What do you mean by a "further expansion of the series does not lead to a reversal in the sign of the expression"?

Comment: The second derivative test is an immediate consequence of Lagrange's form of the remainder.  It is true if $f$ has a continuous second derivative.  Higher-order derivatives need not even exist, so the question of "further expansion of the series' doesn't arise.